# How to set username and password for plaintext protocol (no SASL) with librdkafka?

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to connect a producer with `security.protocol` conf property to plaintext.
How to pass `username` and `password` to the `Conf` object before invoking `RdKafka::Producer::create` ?

None of the `set` call seems to fit.
I read the doc [about sasl](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka) for inspiration but it did not helped.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far? Did you look at this example? https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/producer.cpp

Comment: Yes, I checked it, nothing about setting any login/pwd. I runned the example there (working fine without credential) and tried to add auth infos with keys "username", "sasl_username" ...

Comment: The page https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/librdkafka/md_CONFIGURATION.html do not provide any information about passing login/passwd when security.protocol=plaintext ...

Comment: In your code, you set the following keys: "sasl.username", "sasl.password", and "security.protocol"? Set security.protocol = sasl_plaintext if SSL is not enabled in your broker and set security.protocol = sasl_ssl if encryption is enabled.

Comment: I set security.protocol=plaintext : this value is not valid ? I want plaintext protocol !

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sasl.username
sasl.password
```

Comment: Whilst code-only answers might provide a solution to the initial problem, they don't provide any explanation to the author as to why they work. Please, consider adding more details to your answer.